# Pushing value of Var into an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, push

I know this is probably a simple question, but I'm attempting a tweak in a plugin & js is not my expertise and I got stumped on how to do the following:

I have an array that can contain a number of values ($fruit) depending on what a user has entered. I want to add another variable to the array that isn't determined by manual input.

I know push should apply here but it doesn't seem to work, why does the following syntax not work?

```
var veggies = "carrot";
var fruitvegbasket = $('#fruit').val();
fruitvegbasket.push(veggies);
```

---

update: 
I got it working doing this:

```
var fruit = $('#fruit').val();
var veggies = "carrot";
fruitvegbasket = new Array();
fruitvegbasket.push(fruit+","+veggies);
```

not sure that's the best way to do it, but it works. thanks all!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Off the top of my head I think it should be done like this:

```
var veggies = "carrot";
var fruitvegbasket = [];
fruitvegbasket.push(veggies);
```

Answer (score 6):

jQuery is not the same as an array. If you want to append something at the end of a jQuery object, use:

```
$('#fruit').append(veggies);
```

or to append it to the end of a form value like in your example:

```
 $('#fruit').val($('#fruit').val()+veggies);
```

In your case, `fruitvegbasket` is a string that contains the current value of `#fruit`, not an array.

jQuery ([jquery.com](http://jquery.com)) allows for DOM manipulation, and the specific function you called `val()` returns the `value` attribute of an `input` element as a string. You can't push something onto a string.

Comment: Do you not need a `','+` before `veggies`?

Answer (score 1):

`.val()` does not return an array from a DOM element: `$('#fruit')` is going to find the element in the document with an ID of #fruit and get its value (if it has a value).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `$('#fruit').val();` is not returning an array and you need something like:

```
$("#fruit").val() || []
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/val